# header logo overlapping with html content on print view in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Does anyone have a link to an article or working example of repeating page headers from Chrome specifically?

I've spent days on this with no luck, there are several Stack proposed solutions but none seem to work (in Chrome). Since we use Chrome at work I've only tested there, so a lot these below say Chrome just can't do it, but maybe I overlooked something?

Comment: You'll need to post your code so we can help you.

Comment: table, table tr td, table tr th {
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.view_transcript .logo-sss:before {
  
  position:fixed;
  content:url(../css/themes/images/logo.svg);
 height: 31px;
 width: 163px;
 top:0;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.m-top-25 {
 margin-top: 25px;
}
@page {
 margin-top:2cm;
}

Comment: Add your full html and css code or create a link of your code by inserting them in jsfiddle.

Comment: Read here how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use chrome to download firefox https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/ I don't know anything about your problem but you did say there were solutions maybe ff can be a part of that solution.

Comment: Can share your HTML code and CSS, if possible share the screenshot of the issue.? So we can help you.

Comment: Sanjay, it seems some new bug on chrome. I´ve a page that worked grea for years and it suddenly stops to print fancy after some chrome update. It prints well only the first page, but from second page chrome overlap the table header rows. The same html works well in firefox.

Comment: Thanks @Luty for share your comment. For me also same works well in Firefox.